# cannot assign to read only property of object '#<Object>' that a npm library is exposing

Tags: javascript, object, npm, package, javascript-objects

Can't we assign a new value to one of the properties of an object that a npm library is exposing? Even if the library has not frozen that object.

Are objects exposed by a library frozen automatically?

Comment: do you mind adding more details? it might be that the property in non writable. i don't think that they are automatically frozen

Comment: What do you mean by non-writable?
It is something like `export const VAR = {name: {first: "John", last: "Wick"}}` in the package, and in my code, I am doing `VAR.name = {...VAR.name, last: "Doe"}`.

Comment: have a look at writable in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty . Your shrared code above seems legit.